# What is the number beside console log in Firefox/Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

I had put some logs in javascript to check the occurrence of drawElement in WebGL Code. I get drawElement on console but along with it I was also getting some number in firefox as well as chrome. What does that number signify?

[image]

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to attach it.

Comment: Are you talking about the red ones ? Then it's just how many occurrence of the same log has happened in a row

Comment: that is number of times that console printed

Comment: So, instead of printing it multiple time is it printing the number?

Comment: Yes , it prints the number instead of printing multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It denotes The Number of times the statement is printed.

If a same statement is printed multiple times , The number will be shown instead of printing multiple times. The file name from where it is printed is shown next to it.

Sample Code :

```
for(var i = 0 ; i< 5; i++)
{
   console.log("Print");
   // The Same statement will be printed 5 Times
}
for(var i = 0 ; i< 5; i++)
{
   console.log(i);
  // Different values for i will be printed in every iteration like 1,2,3.
}
```

JsFiddle Link :

> https://jsfiddle.net/19ng1p8p/